# SSIS csv source file

Tags: csv, ssis, etl, data-cleaning

My source file is a CSV file which contains this type of data

```
fullname, salary
ajit, 5000
saroj, kumar, 4000
suni, 3000
mohan, das, 2000
```

and I need the output to be something like:

```
fullname    | salary
------------|-------
ajit        | 5000
saroj kumar | 4000
suni        | 3000
mohan das   | 2000
```

how to solve this by using SSIS

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to pre-process the csv file with a script task.  You need to re-write the file so it is a valid csv format.  In the small sample that you showed, you could just remove the first comma anytime there is more than one comma on a line, for instance.

Then you would be able to import the file normally with a data flow.

Of course, you can also just do the entire import in the script task.

Comment: thanks tab alleman, can you please explain step by step what tasks i need to use for get the data from source and load the data in sql server destination table.

Comment: No, sorry, that would make my answer entirely too long, and would duplicate information that is already freely available on the internet.   Which step of the process do you not know how to do?